# Adding values to an associative array, where some key=> value pairs are incomplete

Tags: php, arrays

Why does the below code not assume an empty 'value' pair for the specified 'key'?

Take the following example:

```
$key1 = "An element";
$key2 = "Another, without a pair";
$key3 = "A third, with a pair";

$check=Array($key1=>21, $key2, $key3=>23);
```

If outputted using print_r, returns the following:

```
Array ( [An element] => 21 [0] => Another, without a pair [A third, with a pair] => 23 )
```

Rather than:

```
Array ( [An element] => 21 [Another, without a pair] => null [A third, with a pair] => 23 )
```

I want to have an array containing an unknown number of items, all of which may or may not have a key=>value pair. What are my options for ensuring that I get the second result?

Essentially, I want to pass a list of keys from my controller to a function, and for the function to identify them as key->value even if the value is null. Some of the keys might have values set, others might not.

It may be that the best solution lies in the `foreach $key as $value {}` code space, or that I can wrap `$key1` in some form of parenthesis... I'm not sure!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add NULL as shown here.

```
$check=Array($key1=>21, $key2=>NULL, $key3=>23);
```

**To Initialize the array:**

```
$keys = array($key1, $key2, $key3);
$check = array_fill_keys($keys,NULL);
```

Comment: I was hoping to also allow: `$check=Array($key1, $key2, $key3);` Is there another way? (and I know I can do something like `$key1 = $key1=>null`, but that doesn't really suit me either)

Comment: I do not understand exactly what you are trying to do. All PHP sees is you are putting a string into the array without a key.

Comment: Thanks - It may be - I'm seeing if I can make it work. Essentially, I want to pass a list of keys from my controller to a function, and for the function to identify them as key->value even if the value is null.

Comment: @Shahar I created my first large scale perl Web app in 1996.

Comment: @Misunderstood Yeah, I read that on your bio. Impressive life (I actually mean it, I'm not being sarcastic).

Answer (score 0):

It depends in the type of the values.

Using `NULL` is a very common technique, But, if all values, are intended to be of the same type, maybe you would like to use an "empty" value for them, that is not `NULL`.

Example, if the values are integers, you may want to use `0` or `-1` to indicate the value is not assigned. Or `""` for strings.

In case that you are storing different types, then, you may like to use `NULL` as a non typed value.